# How to invoke the scanDouble() method?

Tags: java

I tried to invoke the scanDouble () method in main () but I failed several times

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class validateInput {
    public static void scanDouble(Scanner in){
        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        if(!in.hasNextDouble()){
            String word = in.next();
            System.err.println(word + "is not a number");
            return;
        }
        double x = in.nextDouble();
        printLogarithm(x);
    }

    public static void printLogarithm(double x) {
        if (x < 0.0) {
            System.err.println("Error: x must be positive.");
            return;
        }
        double result = Math.log(x);
        System.out.println("The log of x is " + result);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        double x = in.nextDouble();
        scanDouble(x);
    }

}
```

> error info:validateInput.java:26:error:incompatible type: double cannot convert to Scanner
>   scanDouble(x);

Comment: `scanDouble` takes a `Scanner` parameter, and you are passing a `double` parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void scanDouble(Scanner in){
```

you have to pass a Scanner as argument.

```
double x = in.nextDouble();
        scanDouble(x);
```

you passed a double value into the method